# Nodejs & Sqlite - Why each statement return no results

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve the data from Sqilte DB (using NodeJs).
I want to print into the log every row entry.
For some reason I'm not getting errors but I'm not getting results either.

I'm creating the DB in the following code:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

  var db = new sqlite3.Database('usersDataBase');
  db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usersTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , userName TEXT, password TEXT)");  
  db.close();
```

and adding users with the following code:

```
 var db = new sqlite3.Database('usersDataBase');         
         var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO usersTable VALUES (null, ?, ?)", userName, passw);       
         stmt.finalize();    
         db.close();
```

Finally I'm trying to print the table content with:

```
app.get("/view", function(req, res) {


    var db = new sqlite3.Database('usersDataBase');
    db.each("SELECT * FROM usersTable", function(err, row) {
        if (err) console.log('Error: ' + err);
        else console.log(row.userName + ": " + row.password)
       //db.close();
    });
    //db.close();

    // get to main screen
    console.log('Sending main.html')
    res.sendFile('main.html', {root: __dirname })
})
```

But I'm getting nothing on the screen. (No error message and no results)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Should the db.Close() be the last line. Isn't that closing it before the callbacks are called?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show the error, using the error object as following in one of the three operations  :

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database('usersDataBase');
db.each("SELECT * FROM usersTable", function(err, row) {
   if(err) console.error(err);
   else console.log(row.userName + ": " + row.password);
});
```

a little hint may be out of topic:
Your set of queries might become very complex, so I suggest you to use the **promise** module, for promise mechanism, which might save you for latter time, and make your code more readable, when it becomes complex. 
**promise.denodeify** transform a node callback style function into a promise, (methods whom callbacks have err and result arguments (the order is important)):

```
var promise = require('promise');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('usersDataBase');

var dbEach = promise.denodeify(db.each);

dbEach("SELECT * FROM usersTable")
    .then(onSelectFromUsersTableSuccess)
    .catch(onSelectFromUsersTableError);

function onSelectFromUsersTableSuccess(row) {
    // handle row
}

function onSelectFromUsersTableError(err) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: The 2 ways doesn't work. In the second way I add print in case of error and I'm getting: ' typeerror database object expected'

Comment: I apologize, I edited my awnser to get informed more about the error source.